# SpriteKit - Basic Positioning of a label in a background

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Very new to Sprite Kit and i'm doing some reading now, but wanted to ask about something that I haven't found the best answer to yet.

I'm doing a tutorial with some code that creates a background, and then adds a label to show a score. I started changing the label code to position it on the top-left corner of the screen.

Here is the code (with my edits to the label, gameLabel):

```
 let screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
 let screenWidth = screenSize.width
 let screenHeight = screenSize.height

let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")
    background.position = CGPoint(x: screenWidth / 10, y: (screenHeight / 15) - 100)
    background.blendMode = .Replace
    background.zPosition = -1
    addChild(background)

gameScore = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Chalkduster")
gameScore.text = "Score: 0"
gameScore.position = CGPoint(x: screenWidth / 10, y: (screenHeight / 15) - 100)
gameScore.horizontalAlignmentMode = .Left
gameScore.verticalAlignmentMode = .Top
gameScore.fontSize = 48
addChild(gameScore)
```

So the label is not displaying in any case, and my assumption is this:

Because i'm adding the background first, the label is getting added within the confines of the background, therefore it needs to be positioned differently, perhaps using the label size instead of the screen size?

My questions:

1. How can I get the label to always appear in the top left?
2. The author chose a hard-coded CGPoint for this background image and then said it has to be on an iPad, but i'd like to do it for iPhone 6/plus in landscape as well as iPad. Is there a way I can just make it work on both devices without having to specify a CGPoint like that? Can't it just scale and work regardless?

Thanks and apologies if these are basic questions - i'm going to do my best to continue reading on the subject..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your question has a simple answer to it. You have forgotten and missed out somethings in your code, and I can show you these things.

   In your code you set the background ZPosition to -1, the smallest number will always appear at the back. So if you set the SKLabelNode to a bigger zPosition it will always appear at the front, as maybe there may be a problem with rendering, as I have also experience like these, I fix it this way:

Before you add the LabelNode set it's property to this:

```
gamescore.zPosition = 0
```

0, In this case could just be anything bigger than the backgrounds(or the node that you want to appear at the back). So this just tells the compiler that you want the LabelNode to appear at the front, or in front of the Background.

2. If you want to make a universal app or game, with SpriteKit you will need to add some extra code to your game or app. Since I think that it is better to give you a good tutorial to show you instead of showing you some basics, I will give you a good link on how to do this:

   [SpriteKit: how to make a universal app](http://www.raywenderlich.com/49695/sprite-kit-tutorial-making-a-universal-app-part-1)

I hope this helps, and don't worry this took me some time to figure out my self.